# Concurrency issue in flink stream job

Tags: mysql, apache-flink, flink-streaming

I have a flink streaming job which does user fingerprinting based on click-stream event data. Code snippet is attached below

```
final StreamExecutionEnvironment env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();

    // setting event time characteristic for processing
    env.setStreamTimeCharacteristic(TimeCharacteristic.ProcessingTime);

    DataStream<EventData> input = ConfluentKafkaSource.
            createKafkaSourceFromApplicationProperties(env);

    
    final OutputTag<EventData> emailPresentTag = new OutputTag<>("email-present") {
    };
    final OutputTag<EventData> dispatchIdPresentTag = new OutputTag<>("dispatch-id-present") {
    };
    final OutputTag<EventData> residueTag = new OutputTag<>("residue") {
    };

    SingleOutputStreamOperator<EventData> splitStream = input
            .process(new ProcessFunction<EventData, EventData>() {
                @Override
                public void processElement(
                        EventData data,
                        Context ctx,
                        Collector<EventData> out) {
                    if (data.email != null && !data.email.isEmpty()) {
                        // emit data to side output for emailPresentTag
                        ctx.output(emailPresentTag, data);
                    } else if (data.url != null && data.url.contains("utm_source=starling")) {
                        // emit data to side output for dispatchIdPresentTag
                        ctx.output(dispatchIdPresentTag, data);
                    } else {
                        // emit data to side output for ip/campaign attributing
                        ctx.output(residueTag, data);
                    }
                }
            });

    DataStream<EventData> emailPresentStream = splitStream.getSideOutput(emailPresentTag);
    DataStream<EventData> dispatchIdPresentStream = splitStream.getSideOutput(dispatchIdPresentTag);
    DataStream<EventData> residueStream = splitStream.getSideOutput(residueTag);

    // process the 3 split streams separately based on their corresponding logic
    DataStream<EventData> enrichedEmailPresentStream = emailPresentStream.
            keyBy(e -> e.lbUserId == null ? e.eventId : e.lbUserId).
            window(TumblingProcessingTimeWindows.of(Time.seconds(30))).
            process(new AttributeWithEmailPresent());

    DataStream<EventData> enrichedDispatchIdPresentStream = dispatchIdPresentStream.
            keyBy(e -> e.lbUserId == null ? e.eventId : e.lbUserId).
            window(TumblingProcessingTimeWindows.of(Time.seconds(30))).
            process(new AttributeWithDispatchPresent());

    DataStream<EventData> enrichedResidueStream = residueStream.
            keyBy(e -> e.lbUserId == null ? e.eventId : e.lbUserId).
            window(TumblingProcessingTimeWindows.of(Time.seconds(30))).
            process(new AttributeWithIP());

    DataStream<EventData> dataStream = enrichedEmailPresentStream.union(enrichedDispatchIdPresentStream, enrichedResidueStream);

    final OutputTag<EventData> attributedTag = new OutputTag<>("attributed") {
    };
    final OutputTag<EventData> unattributedTag = new OutputTag<>("unattributedTag") {
    };

    SingleOutputStreamOperator<EventData> splitEnrichedStream = dataStream
            .process(new ProcessFunction<EventData, EventData>() {
                @Override
                public void processElement(
                        EventData data,
                        Context ctx,
                        Collector<EventData> out) {
                    if (data.attributedEmail != null && !data.attributedEmail.isEmpty()) {
                        // emit data to side output for emailPresentTag
                        ctx.output(attributedTag, data);
                    } else {
                        // emit data to side output for ip/campaign attributing
                        ctx.output(unattributedTag, data);
                    }
                }
            });

    //splitting attributed and unattributed stream
    DataStream<EventData> attributedStream = splitEnrichedStream.getSideOutput(attributedTag);
    DataStream<EventData> unattributedStream = splitEnrichedStream.getSideOutput(unattributedTag);

    // attributing backlog unattributed events using attributed stream and flushing resultant attributed
    // stream to kafka enriched_clickstream_event topic.
    attributedStream = attributedStream.windowAll(TumblingProcessingTimeWindows.of(Time.seconds(30))).
            process(new AttributeBackLogEvents()).forceNonParallel();
    attributedStream.
            addSink(ConfluentKafkaSink.createKafkaSinkFromApplicationProperties()).
            name("Enriched Event kafka topic sink");


    //handling unattributed events. Flushing them to mysql
    Properties dbProperties = ConfigReader.getConfig().get(REPORTINGDB_PREFIX);
    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    unattributedStream.addSink(JdbcSink.sink(
            "INSERT IGNORE INTO events_store.unattributed_event (event_id, lb_user_id, ip, event) values (?,?,?,?)",
            (ps, t) -> {
                ps.setString(1, t.eventId);
                ps.setString(2, t.lbUserId);
                ps.setString(3, t.ip);
                try {
                    ps.setString(4, objectMapper.writeValueAsString(t));
                } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
                    logger.error("[UserFingerPrintJob] "+ e.getMessage());
                }
            },
            JdbcExecutionOptions.builder()
                    .withBatchIntervalMs(Long.parseLong(dbProperties.getProperty(REPORTINGDB_FLUSH_INTERVAL)))
                    .withMaxRetries(Integer.parseInt(dbProperties.getProperty(REPORTINGDB_FLUSH_MAX_RETRIES)))
                    .build(),
            new JdbcConnectionOptions.JdbcConnectionOptionsBuilder()
                    .withUrl(dbProperties.getProperty(REPORTINGDB_URL_PROPERTY_NAME))
                    .withDriverName(dbProperties.getProperty(REPORTINGDB_DRIVER_PROPERTY_NAME))
                    .withUsername(dbProperties.getProperty(REPORTINGDB_USER_PROPERTY_NAME))
                    .withPassword(dbProperties.getProperty(REPORTINGDB_PASSWORD_PROPERTY_NAME))
                    .build())).name("Unattributed event ReportingDB sink");


    env.execute("UserFingerPrintJob");
```

Steps involved:

1. Splitting the stream to 3 streams based on 3 criteria and then attributing them with email and then collecting as union of these 3 streams.
2. Events which are unattributed in above step are sinked to mysql as backlog unattributed events.
3. Events which are attributed are passed on to AttributeBackLogEvents ProcessFunction. I'm assuming issue is here.
   In AttributeBackLogEvents function, I'm fetching all events from mysql which have cookie-id(lb_user_id) or ip present in input attributed events. Those events are then attributed and percolated down to the kafka sink along with input attributed events. For some of these unattributed events, **I'm seeing duplicate attributed events with timestamp difference of 30seconds**(which is the processing time window). What i think is that while one task of  AttributeBackLogEvents function is still processing, a seaparate task is fetching the same events from mysql and both the tasks are processing simultaneously. Basically i want to enforce record level lock in mysql/code so that same event don't get picked up. One way may be to use select for update, but given the size of data can lead to deadlock(or will this approach be useful?). I tried forceNonParallel() method too but isn't helpful.

Comment: If you have an idea where the problem might lie, try to isolate it. Currently the code and description is quite long, if the problem can be narrowed down to 1 point and you can provide the minimum reproducible example it is much easier for people to help you.

Comment: @DennisJaheruddin I figured out actual issue and had posted another separate question for the same issue at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69402965/flink-what-happens-when-processallwindowfunction-takes-more-time-than-the-tumbl

Comment: Normally I would recommend editing the existing question, but I guess it is alright. However please think whether this original question is still relevant, if not (because the new one succeeded it) the advice is to delete this one to keep the site clean.