# Flink: What happens when ProcessAllWindowFunction takes more time than the TumblingProcessingTimeWindows defined in windowAll()

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

I have a ProcessAllWindowFunction implementation(refer AttributeBackLogEvents() in the code below) which has quite a few I/O and it might take more than 30seconds. windowAll() is windowing data using TumblingProcessingTimeWindows of 30seconds.

```
attributedStream
            .windowAll(TumblingProcessingTimeWindows.of(Time.seconds(30)))
            .process(new AttributeBackLogEvents())
            .forceNonParallel()
            .addSink(ConfluentKafkaSink.createKafkaSinkFromApplicationProperties())
            .name("Enriched Event kafka topic sink");
```

AttributeBackLogEvents fetches a set of events from MySQL based on the iterable passed and after some processing deletes some of the fetched events of MySQL. I'm seeing that the record which cuurent window is fetching(and ideally which should be deleted before the next window fires), is also getting fetched by next window which means even though current window is processing next window fires up.

My questions are:

1. Is it possible that AttributeBackLogEvents is still running and next window fires?
2. If so, then how can i enforce that until current window processing is complete, next window shouldn't fire.

Answer (score 0):

This Q does not describe what happens in the logic, but conceptually:
Your window means 'time range of source data' so any processing of that can never fully be done before the next window starts.

There may be a way, but for a streaming tool a source like MySQL is typically seen as reference data (which you typically want to read often) unless you are doing Change Data Capture.